# Disabling Fullscreen With Double Tap on JWPlayer For iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, jwplayer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` (doubleTap) to a `JWPlayerController` in my app.

Currently, when you double tap a video (JWPlayer) right now it launches by default in full screen mode. The desired behavior is for this gesture to be tied to a different event (liking, à la Most), and for users who want the video fullscreen can use the fullscreen-expansion button instead.

In the SDK it appears that you're only able to alter the Boolean `isInFullScreen` and that *disabling* the double-tap-to-fullscreen function is not feasible. Is this true?

Here's is the gesture that I'm trying to attach to the `player` where currently it's attached to `mediaHeaderView`.

```swift
private extension Selector {
    static let doubleWasTapped = #selector(MediaViewController.doubleWasTapped(_:))
}

final class MediaViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mediaHeaderView: UIView!

    weak var mediaPageDelegate: MediaPageDelegate?
    var viewModel: MediaTableViewModel!
    private var player: JWPlayerController?

    // etc

    addDoubleTapGesture()
}

func doubleWasTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    viewModel.toggleLikeProducer.start()
}

func addDoubleTapGesture() {
    let doubleTappedGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleWasTapped))
    doubleTappedGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTappedGR.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    mediaHeaderView!.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTappedGR)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with the jwplayer team recently. Looking at the code you see that `isInFullScreen` is a readonly property (looking at the name it makes sense). The only current and not so nice fix they provide is to disable the controls over the config file (`config.controls`). I you set this to false the double tap to fullscreen is not working anymore. Also there is this post on their website: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/8123742-disable-fullscreen

Comment: Link is dead :( What did it say?

Comment: It basically suggested what I wrote.